# OpenCart - Not all products showing on category pages

Tags: php, opencart

[Here](https://www.bigbrothersystems.com/cctv-cameras) is only 18 products showing but there should be 25 or so.

> In  settings > option > items - this is set at 100...

Any ideas how to fix as inherited the site and not an open cart expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, Here, have only 18 products available in your main category(cctv-cameras). here, you have not added subcategory products in the main category(cctv-cameras).

if, You want to show all the products in the main category. So, You will need to add subcategory products in both categories (sub and main).

Go to `admin > Catalog > Products > Edit your subcategory product > Links >` & then You can see `"Categories" option >` You can select category. which you want to show the product in the category.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have two ways, you can add every product to the main category and its sub category or you can just edit the code to show the sub category products on the main category.

Go to `catalog/controller/product/category.php`and find this replace with`'filter_category_id' => $category_id` to `'filter_sub_category' => true`
after this all 25 products will show on that category.